# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between this and that

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have data from 2 different databases, which i need to consolidate and compare which each other.

An example:

```
select distinct CustomerNo from DB1.dbo.TableCustomers
UNION ALL
select distinct CustNo from DB2.dbo.NewTableCustomers
```

I get the *Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS" and "Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AS" in the UNION operation* error. 
Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Use an explicit `collate` on the column causing the problem.  Then, fix your database and tables so they all use the same collation!

Comment: Change to `CustomerNo COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` and `CustNo COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` or use `Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AS` in both places. Then, as Gordon suggested, fix your databases so they're consistent.

Comment: select distinct combined with union all. A bit odd combination.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the quick respons. The thing is i'm comparing data with an old system we do not use any more. The data has not been converted to the new system, due to some invoice stuff.

Comment: Can you show me how collate used on the above example? does it require altering the tables? I'm not authorized to change the tables

Comment: You don't need to alter your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct CustomerNo collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS from DB1.dbo.TableCustomers
UNION ALL
select distinct CustNo from DB2.dbo.NewTableCustomers
```

Comment: Hi man, this works perfectly, is there a way to use a single distinct across both tables/databases?

Comment: I just used union instead of Union all and the distinct worked fine, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to use a single count on both statements?

Comment: Post a different question for that